# 2016 Icon Size and Names?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

What is the current list of Icon Sizes and Names? Using Xcode 7

Example Launch set:

```
iPhone3g : 320 x 480

iPhone4/4s : 640 x 960

iPhone5/5s : 640 x 1136

iPhone6 : 750 x 1334

iPhone 6plus : 1242 x 2208
-------------------------------

iPhone3g : 'Default.png'

iPhone4/4s : 'Default@2x.png'

iPhone5/5s : 'Default-568h@2x.png'

iPhone6 : 'Default-667h@2x.png'

iPhone6plus : 'Default-736h@3x.png'
```

Comment: These are the **Launch Images**, _not_ icons. Also, consider using launch  storyboards instead. It's 2016 and iOS 10 is just around the corner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a matrix of the sizes from Apple.

Update: The link is gone, but a copy is available here -

http://web.archive.org/web/20160322170515/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Here is an updated link on Apple's site. It is not quite the same page, but it is similar.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199231/is-it-okay-to-leave-out-unnecessary-launch-images Any idea why? Thanks. BTW, the link is broken.

Comment: Sorry the link is gone! Try this copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20160322170515/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html