# Application icons is pixelated

Tags: ios, icons

I'm trying to set an icon for my app, however the icons derived from the original image are pixelated and look bad.  I tried to provide the app icon gear application with images of different sizes, however the result is still unpleasant.

Should I provide it with images of higher resolution or lower resolution to get better results?

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910886/2016-icon-size-and-names) links to to a matrix provided by Apple for icon sizes.  Should I use these sizes strictly, consider them as a lower border not to go under, or consider them as a ceiling not to exceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs states

> Table 45-1 lists the sizes required for these custom icons and images.

Use the exact sizes.