# Is it okay to leave out unnecessary launch images?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, launchimage

I have an app that supports only iPhones running iOS 10 or above.

I added only the following images:

- Default-568h@2x.png
- Default-667h@2x.png
- Default-736h@3x.png

I left out:

- landscape, since I assume iOS will use the portait one if landscape is missing.
- iPad, since my app supports iPhone only.
- 3.5-inch iPhones, since I require iOS 10, which doesn't run on 3.5-inch iPhones.

**Unfortunately, my UIWindow size is 320 x 658 points on the iPhone 7 Plus, rather than the 414 x 736 it should be. iOS thinks that I support only 4-inch screens, so renders my UI at that size and then expands it, making everything looks huge.**

How do I fix this?

I'm not using storyboards or xibs. Please don't suggest that I use them. That's offtopic for this question.

When the above didn't work, I tried adding Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png, but it didn't help.

I also tried using an asset catalog, but that didn't work, either, as discussed in [this separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168145/whats-wrong-with-my-launch-images).

Comment: you are doing fine and its okay, proceed as you are going.

Comment: Why not use a launch storyboard and avoid the whole image size issue?

Comment: I don't want to get into that here, as the question requests. I'd appreciate an answer to the given question, specifically the wrong UIWindow size.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra It doesn't, as the bold text in the updated question says.

Comment: Did you leave some older `Default.png` behind? Check this post on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21668673/301790

Answer (score 2):

Launch images are about to be dropped completely. The only acceptable app submissions will be those with a launch storyboard. These rules are slated to go into effect in April 2020. So get ready now. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/?time=103.